# XSLT 1.0 grouping to reformat element defined by date into element defined by task

Tags: xslt, grouping, muenchian-grouping

I have a tricky XSLT transformation and I'd like your advise 
My xml is formatted as below:

```
<Person>
<name>John</name>
<date>June12</date>
<workTime taskID=1>34</workTime>
<workTime taskID=2>12</workTime>
</Person>
<Person>
<name>John</name>
<date>June12</date>
<workTime taskID=1>21</workTime>
<workTime taskID=2>11</workTime>
</Person>
```

The output xml should be:

```
<Person>
<name>John</name>
<taskID>1</taskID>
<workTime>
    <date>June12</date>
    <time>34</time>
</worTime>
<workTime>
    <date>June13</date>
    <time>21</time>
</worTime>
</Person>
<Person>
<name>John</name>
<taskID>2</taskID>
<workTime>
    <date>June12</date>
    <time>12</time>
</worTime>
<workTime>
    <date>June13</date>
    <time>11</time>
</worTime>
</Person>
```

Essentially, as an input, a "Person" object gathers all the task/workTime for a specific date. As an output, I want the "Person" object to gather the date/workTime for a specific task.

I need to use XLST 1.0.
I've been trying to use grouping with key but get very puzzled.

Appreciate your help.
Daniel

Comment: Where does the date "June13" come from? This does not appear in your original XML? Should the second June12 in the original XML actually be June13? Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe one way to solve it is to use muenchian grouping, but in this case you are grouping by task and by person, and so you need an aggregated key

```
<xsl:key name="PersonTasks" match="workTime" use="concat(@taskID, ../name)"/>
```

This key is used to look up all distinct 'person tasks'. You would iterate over this by doing the following

```
<xsl:apply-templates select="//workTime[generate-id() = generate-id(key('PersonTasks',concat(@taskID, ../name))[1])]"/>
```

Then, for each distinct Person and TaskID, you just need to find all the work times. Try this stylesheet (Note I have added a 'People' element, to give the output a single root element to ensure it is valid XML)

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

   <xsl:key name="PersonTasks" match="workTime" use="concat(@taskID, ../name)"/>

   <xsl:template match="/">
      <People>
         <xsl:apply-templates select="//workTime[generate-id() = generate-id(key('PersonTasks',concat(@taskID, ../name))[1])]"/>
      </People>
   </xsl:template>

   <xsl:template match="workTime">
      <xsl:variable name="taskID">
         <xsl:value-of select="@taskID"/>
      </xsl:variable>
      <xsl:variable name="name">
         <xsl:value-of select="../name"/>
      </xsl:variable>
      <Person>
         <name>
            <xsl:value-of select="$name"/>
         </name>
         <taskID>
            <xsl:value-of select="$taskID"/>
         </taskID>
         <xsl:for-each select="//workTime[../name = $name][@taskID = $taskID]">
            <workTime>
               <date>
                  <xsl:value-of select="../date"/>
               </date>
               <time>
                  <xsl:value-of select="."/>
               </time>
            </workTime>
         </xsl:for-each>
      </Person>
   </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

When you apply this to the following input XML

```
<People>
<Person>             
<name>John</name>             
<date>June12</date>             
<workTime taskID="1">34</workTime>             
<workTime taskID="2">12</workTime>             
</Person>             
<Person>             
<name>John</name>             
<date>June13</date>             
<workTime taskID="1">21</workTime>             
<workTime taskID="2">11</workTime>             
</Person>   
</People>
```

You should get the following output

```
<People>
   <Person>
      <name>John</name>
      <taskID>1</taskID>
      <workTime>
         <date>June12</date>
         <time>34</time>
      </workTime>
      <workTime>
         <date>June13</date>
         <time>21</time>
      </workTime>
   </Person>
   <Person>
      <name>John</name>
      <taskID>2</taskID>
      <workTime>
         <date>June12</date>
         <time>12</time>
      </workTime>
      <workTime>
         <date>June13</date>
         <time>11</time>
      </workTime>
   </Person>
</People>
```